# Auto-indent rules for file extension in Visual Studio Code (vscode)?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio Code to apply specific auto-indent rules for a given file extension? Our current settings.json file is:

```
{
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "files.associations": {
        "**/src/**/*.js": "javascriptreact"
    }
}
```

I did try the following, but it did not work for me:

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "**/src/**/*.js": "javascriptreact",
        "package.json": "json"
    },
    "[javascriptreact]": {
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "editor.tabSize": 4
    },
    "[json]": {
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "editor.tabSize": 2
    }
}
```

I did experiment with `[*.json]`, but that did not work either.

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.15.0.

Comment: Have you changed the default "editor.detectIndentation": true,  to false in your settings as well.  That setting overrides what you are trying to do if left true.

Comment: I tried updating that in the workspace settings, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: It seems to work for me, I'm using the "[json]" rule right in the settings.json file and it definitely changes the tab size.  You can see the spaces count in the lower right of the editor.  I note that if you already have indentation the first tab on a line will match that and then use your new settings.  Do you have a conflicting extension like prettier?

Comment: Yup, that would be it and I needed to reload the window for the change to take place.

Comment: Did you have a conflicting extension?  Or which suggestion fixed it, it isn't clear.  I would put it into a formal answer if I answered it?!  LOL.

Comment: I had a beautify extension that indicated it was for Javascript, but it also seems to have been extending to the *.json files.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[For simplicity, I'll put the various solutions into an answer.]

Vscode has a handy way to edit [language-specific editor settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings).

> Ctr-Shift-P : Preferences: Configure language specific settings...

and chose your language.  Choosing "JavaScript React" will open and create an entry in your settings.json file where you can add javascript react specific editor settings like number of spaces to use for a tab.

Oddly though, the new settings entry is appended to the end of the file while the file is not automatically scrolled to that point.  So scroll to the end of the settings.json file to find your new language-specific entry.  Into that you can put things like :

```
 "[json]": {
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "editor.insertSpaces": true
 }
```

Note that **"editor:detectIndentation"** is defaulted to true so you must change it to **false**  for tabSize and insertSpaces to have any effect.  Making the above change within the settings.json file will immediately show that it is working within that json file (see the Spaces: # item in the lower right corner of the editor).

However, these settings will not change your existing spacings within a file, but new tabs will reflect your changes...

**Unless** you have a conflicting extension that sets the same editor settings.  I knew the "prettier" extension would do so.  The OP @Andre M reports that the extension "beautify" also conflicts with spaces for tabs.