# How to set "Indent using tabs" as the default when creating new files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I set **Indent using tabs** as the default setting for newly created files?

I always have to configure it manually by clicking the tab **Spaces: 2** and then choosing the option **Indent using spaces** whenever I create a new file on my workspace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto-indent rules for file extension in Visual Studio Code (vscode)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806965/auto-indent-rules-for-file-extension-in-visual-studio-code-vscode)

Answer (score 1):

1. Press `Ctr` `Shift` `P`. Then select `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` (It should be the first result).
2. Find the javascript key and add to `"editor.tabSize": 2` it.

   ```
   "[javascript]": {
   "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
   "editor.tabSize": 2
   ```

   },